# Wix installer unexpected error

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am getting below error while running wix installer to install windows service:

*The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 
MSI (s) (20:E0) [12:15:16:924]: Product: ABC.NS.Scheduler.Deployment.SCHEDULER -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: ,*

Below is the are the logs:

```html
=== Logging started: 5/18/2015  12:15:16 ===
Action start 12:15:16: INSTALL.
Action start 12:15:16: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 12:15:16: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: AppSearch.
Action ended 12:15:16: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 12:15:16: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 12:15:16: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: CostInitialize.
Action ended 12:15:16: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: FileCost.
Action ended 12:15:16: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: CostFinalize.
Action ended 12:15:16: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 12:15:16: SetInstallLocationRootDirectory.
DEBUG: Error 2343:  Specified path is empty.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 
MSI (s) (20:E0) [12:15:16:924]: Product: ABC.NS.Scheduler.Deployment.SCHEDULER -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. The arguments are: , , 

Action ended 12:15:16: SetInstallLocationRootDirectory. Return value 3.
Action ended 12:15:16: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {144D75A6-0CCB-4AAC-8547-C904DF2FAE7D}
Property(S): NETFRAMEWORK45 = #379893
```

**CODE:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include Includes\Dependencies.wxi?>
      <Product Id="{51669456-A144-4A44-BE32-958BB4E8CD3D}" 
           Name="ABC.NS.Scheduler.Deployment.SCHEDULER"
           Language="1033"
            Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
            Manufacturer="ABC"
           UpgradeCode="144d75a6-0ccb-4aac-8547-c904df2fae7d">
  <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.LaterVersionAlreadyInstalled)" />
        <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
    <Condition Message="!(loc.DotNetFrameworkIsRequired)">
      Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45
    </Condition>

    <!-- Package the binaries in the msi -->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="CABIIS.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <CustomAction  Id="SetInstallLocationRootDirectory"       Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" Execute="firstSequence" Value="[TARGET.INSTALLLOCATION]" />

    <!-- Set the install location from the trigger file -->

    <CustomAction Id="RunSCHEDULERInstall" Directory="TARGETDIR" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="[SCHEDULERIMPORTERFOLDER]ABC.NS.Scheduler.SCHEDULERService.exe install"/>
    <CustomAction Id="RunSCHEDULERUninstall" Directory="TARGETDIR" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="[SCHEDULERIMPORTERFOLDER]ABC.NS.Scheduler.SCHEDULERService.exe uninstall"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>

      <Custom Action="RunSCHEDULERInstall" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="SetInstallLocationRootDirectory" After="CostFinalize" >Not Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="RunSCHEDULERUninstall" After='InstallInitialize'>(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <!-- The directory structure for installation -->
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WindowsService">
    <Directory Id="SCHEDULERIMPORTERFOLDER" Name="ABC.NS.Scheduler.SCHEDULERService" />
        <Directory Id="LOGFOLDER" Name="Log"/>
   </Directory>
  </Directory>
      
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ABC.NS.Scheduler.Deployment.SCHEDULER" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="SCHEDULERServiceComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How are you installing the package.  This may be a related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226637/.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Where is located your msi package? Network, CD, other? Also, where are you trying to install it? Drive c:?